# C# : XmlWriter not writing to the file although recognising input

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating a program that acts as a to-do list. The 'save' function takes a List of 'Homework' structures, and uses a formatted XmlWriter to write to an xml file to a given file location within the project folder. It uses a full path, not a relative one.
 However, none of the data seems to save to the file despite it iterating correctly (also checked.)
Save Routine reads:

```
static void SaveHomeworks(List<Homework> Tasks)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "\t",
        NewLineOnAttributes = true
    };

    XmlWriter XMLWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Path, xmlWriterSettings);//Assigns the file to write to, given the settings of the writer.
    XMLWriter.WriteStartDocument();//starts writing the XML Document
    XMLWriter.WriteStartElement("Data");

    foreach (Homework ThisHomework in Tasks)
    {
        XMLWriter.WriteStartElement("Homework");//this is a nested element, one user in the collection of users      
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("Title", ThisHomework.Title);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("Desc", ThisHomework.Description);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("Subject", ThisHomework.Subject);
        DateTime ThisDueDate = ThisHomework.DueDate;
        string Day = Convert.ToString(ThisDueDate.Day);
        string Month = Convert.ToString(ThisDueDate.Month);
        string Year = Convert.ToString(ThisDueDate.Year);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("DueDateDay", Day);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("DueDateMonth", Month);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("DueDateYear", Year);
        string Imp = Convert.ToString(ThisHomework.ImportanceLevel);
        XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("Importance", Imp);
        if (ThisHomework.IsComplete == true)
        {
            XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("IsComplete", "1");
        }
        else
        {
            XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString("IsComplete", "0");
        }
        XMLWriter.WriteEndElement();//this is the end of a "homework." (Still in the outer element "Data")...
    }
    XMLWriter.WriteEndDocument();//This closes ALL open elements regardless of nesting, but make sure you finish the current element!
    XMLWriter.Close();//closes the file itself.
}
```

The properties for HomeworkData.xml are:

`Build Action: Content
 Copy To Output Directory: Do not copy
 Custom Tool : (blank)
 Custom Tool Namespace : (blank)
 File Name : HomeworkData.xml
 Full Path :"c:\users\MY_ACCOUNT\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewHomeworkManager\NewHomeworkManager\HomeworkData.xml"`

if it helps, the string 'Path' is 
`c:\users\MY_ACCOUNT\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewHomeworkManager\NewHomeworkManager\HomeworkData.xml`-the same.

I'm running VS 2015 on Windows 10.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong to prevent saves? It used to work but seems not to any more, I may have changed a setting in Visual Studio accidentally. Any pointers are helpful!

Further Edit: Removed LoadHomeworksData info as I have a 30k character limit, and people say that it's fine.

Here also is the method for creating a new homework in the program. (note: date entry is in English not American format for inputs, ie DD/MM/YYYY)

```
static Homework AddNewHomework()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
        var NewHomework = new Homework();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the task.");
        NewHomework.Title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a description of the homework task.");
        NewHomework.Description = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the subject it is from, if any.");
        NewHomework.Subject = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the due date for this piece of homework.\n Please use a '/' symbol to separate it out.");
        DateTime DueDate;
        while (true)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[3];
            string DateToFormat = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                string[] words = DateToFormat.Split('/');
                numbers[0] = int.Parse(words[0]);
                numbers[1] = int.Parse(words[1]);
                numbers[2] = int.Parse(words[2]);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please use '/' symbols to separate the day, month and then year.\n No spaces please.");
            }
            if (numbers[2] != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    DueDate = new DateTime(numbers[2], numbers[1], numbers[0]);
                    if (DueDate >= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a due date that hasn't already happened!");
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid date!");
                }
            }
        }
        NewHomework.DueDate = DueDate;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the importance of the homework, in a rating of 1 to 5.");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                NewHomework.ImportanceLevel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (1 <= NewHomework.ImportanceLevel && NewHomework.ImportanceLevel <= 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer from 1 to 5.");
            }
        }
        NewHomework.IsComplete = false;
        return NewHomework;
    }
```

And this is how it is called in the Main Loop:

```
case ConsoleKey.A:
                    Homework NewHomework = AddNewHomework();
                    Tasks.Add(NewHomework);
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130995/discussion-on-question-by-she3pish-c-xmlwriter-not-writing-to-the-file-althou).

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The methods `SaveHomeworks` and `LoadHomeworksData` are not at fault, when used with a valid `List<Homework>` and valid `XML` file respectively they definitely work. I have successfully used both methods myself on Windows 10 via LinqPad 5.

I assume you get a `FileNotFound` exception when loading the `XML` file and so an empty list is returned which in turn creates the XML content you've shown. Put a breakpoint in this method on `xmlDoc.Load(Path);` and inspect the value of path, it is likely invalid in some way.

I can't say why modifying the list isn't working without seeing those methods. I assume somewhere you lose the reference to the list or you accidentally create a new one which is empty.

Here is an example that manually creates a list of Homework and passes it to `SaveHomeworks`, this works fine.

```
var list = new List<Homework>();

var one = new Homework()
{
    Title = "Title 1",
    Description = "Description",
    Subject = "Subject",
    DueDate = new DateTime(2016,1,1),
    ImportanceLevel = 1,
    IsComplete = false
};

var two = new Homework()
{
    Title = "Title 2",
    Description = "Description",
    Subject = "Subject",
    DueDate = new DateTime(2016,1,1),
    ImportanceLevel = 1,
    IsComplete = false
};

var three = new Homework()
{
    Title = "Title 3",
    Description = "Description",
    Subject = "Subject",
    DueDate = new DateTime(2016,1,1),
    ImportanceLevel = 1,
    IsComplete = false
};

list.Add(one);
list.Add(two);
list.Add(three);

SaveHomeworks(list);
```

Comment: The `LoadHomeworksData`path seems valid, and following it reaches where it should, and to the xml file. I'll add the AddHomework method to the question.

Comment: Well it either **is** or **is not** valid, which one is it? Post it if you're not sure. I'll have a look at the extra method, but it's really irrelevant. Whatever `List<Homework>` you eventually pass to `SaveHomeworks` is empty, that's all there is to it.